# Наложить картинку с transform на canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, transform

Есть canvas. Есть картинка  с абсолютной позицией, которую можно перемещать поверх canvas. Можно ее "отпечатать" на canvas, просто вызвав drawImage с отступами картинки. Если у картинки есть свойство transform rotateY (причем, судя по моим экспериментам, только rotateY), drawImage учитывает его и правильно отображает. RotateX, rotateZ не учитывает. Мою картинку можно крутить по всем осям, а так же применено свойство perspective: [image: rotateX + rotateY + rotateZ + perspective]

Необходимо отпечатать ее на canvas в таком виде, чтобы потом сохранить это все как 1 картинку.
ctx.transform не учитывает perspective.